# Functors from rings to groups

Tags: category-theory

> For any commutative ring $K$, the set of all non-singular $n\times n$ matrices with entries in $K$ is the usual general linear group $\operatorname{GL}_n(K)$; moreover, each homomorphism $f:K\to K'$ of rings produces in the evident way a homomorphism $\operatorname{GL}_nf:\operatorname{GL}_n(K)\to \operatorname{GL}_n(K')$ of groups. These data define for each natural number $n$ a functor $\operatorname{GL}_n:\operatorname{CRng}\to \operatorname{Grp}$.

These lines come from MacLane, Categories for the working mathematician. What happens if I remove "commutative"? In other words, $\operatorname{GL}_n:\operatorname{Rng}\to \operatorname{Grp}$ is still a functor?

Comment: what is the evident way to define $GL_nf$?

Comment: @john I suppose $A\to B$, with $b_{ij}=f(a_{ij})$

Comment: yeah right that works.

Comment: I see no reason to demand commutativity. $GL_n(K)$ is still a group for a non commutative ring and $GL_nf$ still a homomorphism. If you want to prove it just check the axioms ;)

Comment: there is probably some reason why he wants to focus on commutative rings

Comment: Perhaps MacLane focused on nonsingular because determinant and therefore non-singular become more complicated. However if you define $\operatorname{GL}_n(K)$ to be the units group of $M_n(K)$, then you're ok.

Comment: I think it's in quite poor taste to mix up the names of recently dead mathematicians to get your username.

Answer (score 2):

No commutativity of multiplication is necessary, and by the way also no subtraction. If $R$ is any [semiring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring), we can form the semiring of matrices $M_n(R)$ over $R$. Clearly, this defines a functor $M_n : \mathbf{SemiRing} \to \mathbf{SemiRing}$. We also have the forgetful functor $U : \mathbf{SemiRing} \to \mathbf{Mon}$ (forgets addition) and the group of units functor $(-)^{\times} : \mathbf{Mon} \to \mathbf{Grp}$. The composition of these functors is a therefore also a functor, namely $\mathrm{GL}_n : \mathbf{SemiRing} \to \mathbf{Grp}$. You can also restrict it to the subcategory of rings.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2921693/matrices-over-noncommutative-rings